# Is there any way to "request transfer" from another EOS account without "multisig"

Tags: transactions, transfer, multisig

imagine I have account A and account B.

Account A would like to ask B to transfer him some EOS tokens.
Is it technically possible to:

- create a multisig request transaction from A side: "B, please sign this to automatically transfer me back 10 Tokens"
- A signs incoming transaction
- B receives funds from A.

It's do-able with the help of "multisig" and I would like to see if there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Account B could give account A permission to access his account's transfer action. But that wouldn't limit the amount of money that was transferable, so it would be very dangerous for account B to do this. However, to do it you would set up the permissions such that there was a threshold of 1, with both account B and account A having weight 1.

Comment: True, I can't share access to accounts.